# How to create a class containing different JavaFx tasks?

Tags: java, javafx, task

So I'm using JavaFX tasks for different kinds of methods that get data from an online service - this can take time so I don't want the UI to freeze.

To make the tasks I've created a separate class for each of them to be called on by other classes in my application.

However, there are many different types of things I want to get from the online service and I don't want to create a new class for each one. All the implementations of Tasks I see online have them as classes.

Can I have a single "NetworkTasks" class that contains many tasks? This would be much cleaner and easier to work with than many separate Task class files.

**EDIT:** Example of a Task class. This lookups a list of usernames when given a name using a external networking class that returns a list of names. This can take time so it would freeze the UI if it wasn't a Task

```
public class NameLookupTask extends Task<ArrayList<Label>> {


public UsernameSearchTask(NetworkClient client, String name) {
    this.client = client;
    this.name= name;
}

@Override
protected ArrayList<Label> call() throws Exception {
    String[] userMessages;
    userMessages = client.getMessages().getName();
    System.out.println(userMessages.length);
    ArrayList<Label> newNames= new ArrayList();
    if (userMessages.length != 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < userMessages.length; i++) {
            Label newName= new Label(name);
            newMessages.add(newMessage);
            updateProgress(i, userMessages.length);
        }
    } else {
        this.cancel(true);
    }
    return newNames;
}
```

}

I want to have multiple tasks like this, but for other data, just getting the data and turning into UI elements. Can it all be in one class file?

Comment: Do those tasks have enough in common to share logic? This very much depends on the kind of info you're retrieving, the info you're extracting and the output format... There's no way to answer this in general...

Comment: @fabian it's the same logic, just extracting different information

Comment: This info isn't helpful. Post 2 or 3 examples (simplified, if necessary) and we should be able to help... This may be as simple as passing an xpath or not possible without making things more complicated than writing seperate code for every source of information...

Comment: @fabian I've added an example